# Bash trap not working if script started from another sript

Tags: linux, bash, signals

bash script a.sh:

```
...
trap "echo 'Got SIGQUIT';" SIGQUIT
...
```

bash script b.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.sh &
./a.sh &
./a.sh &
```

if I start "./a.sh &" from command line, trap is working. If I run "./b.sh &" traip on a.sh script is no longer responding to SIGQUIT.

Comment: How are you delivering `SIGQUIT` to the `a` processes? If you are sending it `b` and expecting `b` to pass it on to the background jobs, that doesn't happen.

Comment: I was sending SIGQUIT to a.sh .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has something to do with SIGQUIT. Changed it to SIGUSR1 and everything is working fine.